# Get globals from other sites

Tags: templating, localization, globals, multi-site

How would I get the global variables associated to other sites?

For example, in an instance where I have three websites under the group `languages` for the English, Spanish, and French versions. I have specified `companyInformation` globals that contain: phone, address, and logo.

From a template I would like:
- Loop through all sites under the group `languages`
- Get `companyInformation` global values for each of the sites

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is

```
public function getSetByHandle(string $globalSetHandle, int $siteId = null)
```

Thus you can grab all the siteIds you want and loop through them

```
{% for siteId in sites %}
    {% set setForSiteId = craft.app.getGlobals().getSetByHandle('handle', siteId) %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Robin! Just for clarity purposes:

We'd grab all sites with: `{% set sites = craft.app.sites.getAllSites() %}`

And then use the loop you provided as follows:

````
{% for site in sites %}
    {% set siteGlobals = craft.app.getGlobals().getSetByHandle('myGlobalsHandle', site.id) %}
{% endfor %}
````